# Enabling Save as automatically through vba (Without clicking save on prompt)

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

How can I get excel to automatically select save through VBA without manually clicking it. E.g-  I have Code which selects each value on a Data Validation list and gets me to the stage below, although I have to click save each time.

I have tried adding in:

```
  Application.EnableEvents = True
```

But it still only takes me to the stage on the image.

```
    Sub PDFActiveSheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim myFile As Variant
    Dim strFile As String
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    'enter name and select folder for file
    ' start in current workbook folder
    strFile = Cells.Range("B1") & " Period " & Cells.Range("J1")

    strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFile

    myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
         (InitialFileName:=strFile, _
            FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
            Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

    If myFile <> "False" Then
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False, _
        From:=1, _
        To:=2  
   End If   
    exitHandler:
        Exit Sub
    errHandler:
        MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
        Resume exitHandler

    End Sub
```

Comment: Didn't we address this already? Your code explicitly prompts for a file name. If you don't want that just use `strFile` in the code that exports the worksheet to PDF and remove the `GetSaveAsFilename` part.

Comment: Hi @Rory We did, I added in the loop through part relating to the DV List which works fine and also the Folder function. I couldnt get my head around bypassing the prompt as it loops through each value, and felt i didnt explain it very well.

Comment: That was my fault - I just realised it would still prompt for the folder on each pass. I've posted an answer here with code to just export the PDF.

Comment: well asked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid prompting:

```
Sub PDFActiveSheet()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strPath As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim strFile As String
On Error GoTo errHandler

Set ws = ActiveSheet

'enter name and select folder for file
' start in current workbook folder
strFile = Cells.Range("B1") & " Period " & Cells.Range("J1")

strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFile & ".PDF"

    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=strFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False, _
    From:=1, _
    To:=2

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler

End Sub
```